# Adding Data Template with a Template Selector through code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, templates

I have to create a `DataTemplate` through code. This is my code here:

```
    public DataTemplate getTemplate(int r)
    {
        string xaml = "<DataTemplate> " +
                  " <ListView Margin=\"0\" x:Name=\"lv0\" ItemTemplateSelector=\"{StaticResource MyTemplateSelector}\" MinWidth=\"50\"  MinHeight=\"20\"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility=\"Hidden\" BorderBrush=\"{x:Null}\" BorderThickness=\".2\" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility=\"Hidden\"  HorizontalAlignment=\"Stretch\"  Width=\"Auto\" ItemsSource=\"{Binding Events_" + r + "}\" Foreground=\"{x:Null}\" Background=\"{x:Null}\">" +
                    "  <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>" +
                     "     <Style TargetType=\"ListViewItem\">" +
                      "        <Setter Property=\"Padding\" Value=\"0\"/>" +
                       "       <Setter Property=\"HorizontalContentAlignment\" Value=\"Stretch\" />" +
                        "  </Style>" +
                      "</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>" +
                      "<ListView.ItemsPanel>" +
                       "   <ItemsPanelTemplate>" +
                       "       <VirtualizingStackPanel" +
     " Orientation=\"Horizontal\"" +
     " IsItemsHost=\"True\"/>" +
       "                   </ItemsPanelTemplate>" +
        "              </ListView.ItemsPanel>" +            
         "         </ListView>" +
          "    </DataTemplate>";
          MemoryStream sr = null;
        ParserContext pc = null;
        sr = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xaml));

        pc = new ParserContext();
        pc.XmlnsDictionary.Add("", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation");

        pc.XmlnsDictionary.Add("x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml");

        DataTemplate datatemplate = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(sr, pc);
        return datatemplate;
    }
```

The `DataTemplate` is returned just fine. But if you notice my XAML above, you can see that I am using a `DataTemplateSelector` inside the `ListView` as well. In my XAML, there is a selector:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:TaskListDataTemplateSelector x:Key="MyTemplateSelector"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

When I run the code, my `DataTemplate` is returned fine. But when it tries to run, it cannot find the resource named `MyTemplateSelector`. When I see my `ResourceDictionary` in code, I see the selector's index is below the index of `DataTemplate`s in `ResourceDictionary` collection. So I assume that my `DataTemplate` is trying to find `MyTemplateSelector` but is unable to because it is stored below in collection.

What I am doing wrong here? Any suggestions?

Comment: It's hard to comment or answer without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly shows what you're doing. But, have you tried simply looking up the selector in the resources explicitly in code and assigning to the property in your generated `DataTemplate` object (i.e. in the contained `ListView` template)? Also, not that this should affect the outcome here, but IMHO it would be more correct to use UTF8 instead of ASCII for the XML stream.

Comment: Also, personally...it may be there's an even better way to do this, but for sure I would use my code-behind budget to just explicitly set the `ItemsSource` binding appropriately after the fact, rather than wrestle with dynamically-generated and parsed XAML. (At least, from the code example it appears that's the only reason you're doing this...so that you can format the variable value of `r` into the binding).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Peter. I am not really sure how to explain the things here. Are you trying to say that i can use the datatemplate into Xaml directly, and still bind dynamically without using code behind? The reason i used code behind is only for the reason that I cannot find how to dynamically change my ItemsSource for different listviews created.

Comment: Yes, it seems to me you should be able to do exactly that. You would have to set the binding at run-time via code-behind, and I can't really propose an exact example without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) clearly showing the scenario with which to start. Worst-case scenario, you'd have to set up a binding in the XAML that indirects e.g. through an attached property you define. But I think you should be able to just set the binding directly. Please read the MCVE page carefully; it's important the code example be both _minimal_ and _complete_.

Comment: Ok, Peter, I would make sure next to provide as much code as possible. Since the code is pretty confusing for me as I am writing my first xaml almost after 6 years, so didn't write a clean one. I will try to follow your suggestion of dynamic binding.